# Cannot convert value of type 'NSSet?' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>' (using CoreData)

Tags: core-data, swiftui

Using CoreData I don't know how to solve that problem:

Error: `Cannot convert value of type 'NSSet?' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'`

```
private func displayTopics(subject: Subject) -> some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            List {
                ForEach(subject.topics) { topic in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: Text("Destination"),
                        label: {
                            Text("Navigate")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ForEach does not understand `NSSet`, you have to convert it in array:

```
if subject.topics != nil {
    ForEach(Array(subject.topics! as Set), id: \.self) { topic in
        NavigationLink(
            destination: Text("Destination"),
            label: {
                Text("Navigate")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I access that property "title" of "topic"? ... Value of type 'NSObject' has no member 'title'

Comment: You did not show what's inside `topics`, it is your model... and it is different question.

Comment: how should we proceed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64975300/value-of-type-nsobject-has-no-member-title